# What is the right way to import data to tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and trying to make my own little project. I would like to import my CSV file as a dataset and then I would like to split it into training and testing sets and also to be able to make batches from my dataset.
My CSV file contains 3 columns of numbers so I managed to find these lines of code

```
filenames = ['mydata.csv']
record_defaults = [tf.float32] * 3
dataset = tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset(filenames, record_defaults, header=True, select_cols=[1,2,3])
```

How do I convert this object to tensor or dataset, so I can either split the data or create batches of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool to split your data like `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset[:2], dataset[2], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

For instance if your dataset consists of two features columns and one output label.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on the tensorflow guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_csv_data) , you have the dataset and after this you can preprocess your data using the `Dataset.map()` transformation for a certain defined function. Batching and shuffling could also be done after wards using `dataset.batch(Batch_size)` and `dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=Buffer_Size)`. you can read the guide for further details.